# Gap between two level curves of bivariate CDF

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functions

I consider a bivariate cumulative distribution function $F(x,y)$ and two of its level curves.  I can write these level curves as the graphs of functions $c_1(x)$ and $c_2(x)$. Let's say that $c_2$ corresponds to a higher level, so that 
$$c_2(x)-c_1(x)\geq 0.$$

Can I also conclude that the gap between $c_2$ and $c_1$ is monotonic in $x$ -- that is, in case $F$ is absolutely continuous, can I conclude that 
$$c'_2(x)-c'_1(x)\leq 0$$
for all $x$ or 
$$c'_2(x)-c'_1(x)\geq 0$$
for all $x$?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "level curves" in this context, and why there should be just two of them?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery: There are many level curves but I am interested in analyzing the gap between any two of them. A level curve for level $c$ is the collection of points $\{(x,c(x))\}$ on the plain such that $F(x,c(x))=c$. So $c(.)$ itself is decreasing.

Comment: Ah, okay -- I was thrown off by the "its two level curves" language, but I see what you're asking now.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have any reason to believe the result is true? I'm about 95% sure that you can write down a counterexample but will have to wait until a bit later to try to explicitly do so.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery I now edited the question.  I am really interested if the gap is always monotonic (either decreasing or increasing). I don't know if this is true.

Comment: Fair enough, but do you have a reason to believe that even that slightly weaker version should be true? What makes you bring this question to Math.SE? (To be clear: I think my initial gut feeling may have been wrong. I'm now about 60% convinced that the result *is* true, and that the gap always decreases. But I'm unable to furnish a proof at this time.)

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Pure curiosity, to be honest. I was looking at a CDF of two independent random variables with the support on $[0,1]^2$ and noticed that these gap is decreasing. Then I was wondering if this is always going to be like that for CDFs.

Comment: That is a thoroughly legitimate reason!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the pdf on $[0,1]^2$ given by
\begin{align}
p(x,y)&=6(x-y)^2 \\
F(x,y)&=\int_{u=0}^x\int_{v=0}^y p(u,v)du\, dv = xy(2x^2-3xy+2y^2)
\end{align}

Then the lack of monotonicity is clear from the contour plot for $F$:

[image]

If $c_1$ is the contour for 0.1, and $c_2$ is the contour for 0.2, then the gaps between them are the heights of the second shaded region in the plot.

The calculations can be made unusually explicit because the contour for the quantile $q$ has the formula
$$
\frac{3u^{1/3} + 3x^2 -x^4/u^{1/3} }{6x}, \text{ where }
$$
$$
u = 2x^2 \left(q + \sqrt{q^2-x^4q+7x^8/27}\right)-x^6 
$$

So in particular we can disprove monotonicity by calculating:
\begin{align}
c_2'(0.5)-c_1'(0.5) &= 0.23\\
c_2'(0.9)-c_1'(0.9) &= -0.69
\end{align}

Comment: @AaronMontgomery, I updated with a nicer example.

Comment: Yep, I think you've fixed it. I'm really surprised how elusive this counterexample seemed to be! Clearly I just wasn't looking in quite the right places. Great answer!